# chartjs-4.4.2 and chartjs-plugin-annotation in local library

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm new to chartjs so please bear with me :-)
On debian 12 I've npm installed chart.js and chartjs-plugin-annotation

Versions: chartjs-v4.4.2  chartjs-plugin-annotatio-v1.0.3

Using the above mentioned libraries from local library no rectangle is visible.

Using external libraries

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/0.5.7/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js"></script>
```

the desired rectangle is visible.

If using

```
<script src="javascript/chartjs/chart.umd.js"></script> 
<script src="javascript/chartjs-plugin-annotation/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
```

the rectangle is not visible.

Chrome DevTool is showing no errors.

Rectangle:

```
<script>                                                                        
const tempData = {                                                              
labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
datasets: [{                                                                
    label: 'Temp',                                                          
    fill: false,                                                            
    data: [-5, 0, 5, -10, -5, 12, 15, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0],                    
}]                                                                          
};                                                                              
const chartOptions = {                                                          
annotation: {                                                               
    annotations: [{                      
        drawTime: "beforeDatasetsDraw",                                     
        type: "box",                                                        
        xScaleID: "x-axis-0",                                               
        yScaleID: "y-axis-0",                                               
        borderWidth: 0,                                                     
        yMin: 18,                                                           
        yMax: 32,                                                           
        backgroundColor: "rgba(46, 204, 113, 0.3)"                          
    }]                                                                      
                                                                            
}                                                                           
};                                                                              
const chartConfig = {                                                           
type: 'line',                                                               
options: chartOptions,                                                      
data: tempData,                                                             
}                                                                               
// Create the chart                                                             
var ctx =   document.getElementById('tempChart').getContext('2d');                
new Chart(ctx, chartConfig);                                                    
</script>
```

Can anyone provide a working example using local librariers and chartjs-4.4.2?

Comment: If you could post what you have done so far that would help us identify any problems in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Chart.js` v4, you should use `chartjs-plugin-annotation` v3.

[Box Annotations](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/types/box.html) syntax has changed since your code was written originally.

- `annotation` must now be placed inside `options.plugins`.
- `annotation.annotations` is no longer an array but an object.

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code below and see how it works.

```js
const tempData = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Temp',
    fill: false,
    data: [-5, 0, 5, -10, -5, 12, 15, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0],
  }]
};
const chartOptions = {
  plugins: {
    annotation: {
      annotations: {
        box1: {
          drawTime: 'beforeDatasetsDraw',     
          type: 'box',
          xMin: 'Mar',
          xMax: 'Jun',
          yMin: 5,
          yMax: 15,          
          borderWidth: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(46, 204, 113, 0.3)'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
new Chart('tempChart', {
  type: 'line',
  options: chartOptions,
  data: tempData,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@^3"></script>
<canvas id="tempChart"></canvas>
```